# In C#, is there a way to use an "either or" in the input argument of a method?

Tags: c#, methods, oxyplot

In C#, is there a way to use an "either or" in the input argument of a method? For example, I have the method ScaleXmin and ScaleXmin_scatter which both return the Points property of the input.

```
public double ScaleXmin(LineSeries lineSeries)
{
    return lineSeries.Points[0].X;
}
public double ScaleXmin_scatter(ScatterSeries scatterSeries)
{
    return scatterSeries.Points[0].X;
}
```

Is it possible to combine this into one method that accepts either LineSeries or ScatterSeries? The reason for doing this is because I've duplicated many methods to accommodate LineSeries and ScatterSeries.

After googling this, I stumbled upon generics, and maybe that's the way to do this. But I'm stuck because they both don't inherit the same class, and makes me think it's incompatible with Generics:

```
namespace OxyPlot.Series
{
public class ScatterSeries : ScatterSeries<ScatterPoint>
...
public class LineSeries : DataPointSeries
```

**EDIT:**
Here is an example of what I'd like to run without errors, if possible. Right now I'm getting this error: cannot convert from 'OxyPlot.Series.ScatterSeries' to 'OxyPlot.Series.DataPointSeries' at ScaleXMin(scatter);

```
using OxyPlot.Series;
LineSeries line = new LineSeries();
ScatterSeries scatter = new ScatterSeries();
public double ScaleXMin(DataPointSeries series)
{
    return series.Points[0].X;
}
public void Test()
{
    double x = ScaleXMin(line);
    double y = ScaleXMin(scatter);
}
```

Comment: The way all chart libraries work is by using a base abstract class `Series` or interface `ISeries`. Generics and interfaces can be combined too, to create a generic method that only accepts type of a specific interface

Comment: You are probably looking for [overlaoding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/design-guidelines/member-overloading)

Comment: Interface or method overload. C# is not Javascript/Typescript, you can have the same method name with a different signature

Comment: Both [LineSeries](https://github.com/ylatuya/oxyplot/blob/master/Source/OxyPlot/Series/LineSeries.cs#L39) and [ScatterSeries](https://github.com/ylatuya/oxyplot/blob/master/Source/OxyPlot/Series/ScatterSeries.cs#L45) are derived from `DataPointSeries` which contains your [`Points` property](https://github.com/ylatuya/oxyplot/blob/master/Source/OxyPlot/Series/DataPointSeries.cs#L84). Is there something that prevents your method accepting `DataPointSeries`?

Comment: This sounds like an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) - you have a problem X (perhaps how to render different series?) and think that Y is the solution.When that doesn't work, you ask about Y, not X. What is X here?

Comment: EDIT: i fixed the void error. Also, thanks I will look up interface and overloading. I never had formal C# training, I just needed to know what to look up!

Comment: @TeddyTea overloading won't help - it means simply naming both methods the same. You still have to write both of them. What is the *actual* problem?

Comment: @Panagiotis Kanavos, The code that I've written works but I'm constantly rewriting the same code for LineSeries and ScatterSeries. I originally had only two methods AddScatter(scatter) and AddLine(line) but now I have similar methods duplicate ScaleXMin, ScaleXMax, ScaleYMin, and ScaleYMax both for line and scatter and I thought it might be simpler if I could use the same method, especially if they only use Points.

Answer (score 8):

Looking at the source code of [Oxyplot](https://github.com/ylatuya/oxyplot) I found the two classes your talking about, and their base class [DataPointSeries](https://github.com/ylatuya/oxyplot/blob/master/Source/OxyPlot/Series/DataPointSeries.cs). In `DataPointSeries` I see the property `public IList<IDataPoint> Points` which you are referencing. This makes this a whole lot easier, in that you only need to change the parameter type (and return value) to this:

```cs
public double ScaleXMin(DataPointSeries series)
{
    return series.Points[0].X;
}
```

This uses [polymorphism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polymorphism_(computer_science)), basically, LineSeries inherits from DataPointSeries, and as such an instance of LineSeries is also an instance of DataPointSeries. Meaning we can implicitly cast to a DataPointSeries, this allows us to delegate things to subclasses without having to know those (this is something quite fundamental to Object Oriented Programming). This also allows us to call this method like so:

```cs
LineSeries line = new LineSeries();
// Do things with the LineSeries

var x = ScaleXMin(line);
```

Comment: If I do ScatterSeries scatter = new ScatterSeries() and ScaleXMin(scatter), and I get an error: cannot convert from OxyPlot.Series.ScatterSeries to OxyPlot.Series.DataPointSeries

Comment: What MindSwipe says seems ok. If we see the class declaration `    /// <summary>
    /// Represents a series for scatter plots.
    /// </summary>
    /// <remarks>
    /// See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scatter_plot
    /// </remarks>
    public class ScatterSeries : DataPointSeries ` you could do (DataPointSerie)ScatterSeries to cast

Comment: @Nando Oh I see. I looked up ScatterSeries and noticed that online ScatterSeries for Oxyplot inherits DataPointSeries and in my package, using NuGet for OxyPlot.Wpf it inherits ScatterSeries<ScatterPoint>.  Don't know why but I'm going to troubleshoot that now...

Comment: @MindSwipe, The Oxyplot you've referenced might be an older version or clone. The new Oxyplot is referenced at [new Oxyplot 2.0](https://github.com/oxyplot/oxyplot/blob/develop/Source/OxyPlot/Series/ScatterSeries.cs) and ScatterSeries inherits differently there.